Render React component at once instead of one by one
I am using a react dashboard framework Refine (Next.js with mui) and enabling access control in my project.
The sider items will not render one by one if there is no access control provider available.
So I think the default  wrapper in the sider.tsx cause this behaviour.
I would rather show all at once instead of rendering like this.
Can anyone guide me how I can change this behaviour?

